# Why 'strategem', in the last sentence of Speak Memory by Vladimir Nabokov?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-usage

[Source:](http://www.theguardian.com/culture/2012/jul/29/10-best-last-novel-lines) 'The 10 best… closing lines of books', The Guadian broadsheet, by Robert McCrum

> > "There, in front of us, where a broken row of houses stood between us and the harbour, and where the eye encountered all sorts of **stratagems**, such as pale-blue and pink underwear cakewalking on a clothesline, or a lady's bicycle and a striped cat oddly sharing a rudimentary balcony of cast iron, it was most satisfying to make out among the jumbled angles of roofs and walls, a splendid ship's funnel, showing from behind the clothesline as something `in a scrambled picture – Find What the Sailor Has Hidden – that the finder cannot unsee once it has been seen`."
>
> A brilliant, and moving, mixture of perception and reality. Contrast the incoherent end of William Burroughs's *Naked Lunch*, "No got … C'lom Fliday."

How are arrangements of underwear, and the coincidence of a car and a bicycle, [strategems](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/stratagem)? I may have detected a clue: does the use of 'strategem' somehow relate to the prepositional clause (that I greyed), because words like `scrambled, hidden, finder` suggest something requiring a strategem?

Yet I haven't read the novel, so what's so devious or special about a funnel behind  a clothesline? How does this relate to `Find[ing] What the Sailor Has Hidden`? Yes, I agree that in general, `the finder cannot unsee once it has been seen` [by the finder], but so what? I did try some [literary criticism](https://books.google.com/books?id=ICgm-nDYLrYC&pg=PA71&lpg=PA71&dq=%22There,+in+front+of+us,+where+a+broken+row+of+houses%22&source=bl&ots=JJftl8dX1o&sig=KrapWaVwGrPvNXCqX8BYj6JWTIo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=DuOxVP_VItStyAT3l4LIBw&ved=0CDkQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=%22There%2C%20in%20front%20of%20us%2C%20where%20a%20broken%20row%20of%20houses%22&f=false) but it doesn't seem to clarify this last line as exhaustively as I seek.

Comment: they are strategems because the author says they are. This question is off topic because it asks for literary interpretation of the last sentence of a novel.

Answer (score 2):

When the pink and blue underwear are described as *cakewalking*, one understands them to be placed *above* the clothesline, dancing on it, as it were, not hanging from it. And it is odd to find a lady's bicycle on a *rudimentary balcony*.

So these *stratagems* are devices, in the imaginary *Find What the Sailor has Hidden* drawing, which are designed to trick the eye, to cause it to pass over the images as normal, not out of the ordinary.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is **READ THE NOVEL**

Or look the words up.

Why do you want us to do your **thinking** for you.

This is not a question about English, this is a question suggesting that we interpret a literary passage for you. It is opinion-based. It is also the case you can look the words up. **A strategem is a strategem**. How are we supposed to know more than that?

Comment: While I agree: aren't we usually a bit nicer than the guys over at ELU?

Comment: This should be a reason given to close the question, not an answer.